# Where is GParted located in USB installation file?

Tags: installation

I want to install Ubuntu on my Laptop that already has Windows 7 Home Premium. I have the .ISO image of Ubuntu 12.04.1 which I have burned to USB.  I have successfully booted using USB drive.

I have gone through some tutorials which tells how to install Ubuntu to new partition. Some of these websites recommend using GParted to shrink partition etc. However, I could not find any icon to GParted on the desktop. I tried "System Setting" link but there also I could not find it.

Could anyone help me understand where is GParted located and how do I run it? Please note that I do not have prior experience in Linux/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to shrink Windows with Windows tools and use gparted to create partitions if you want to create in advance. Or you can use installer to create partitions. Reboot Windows after shrink so it can run its chkdsk and repairs to recognize its new size.

You may have the 4 primary partition limit and need to backup and delete one partition. Usually the best one to delete is the vendor tools, but do not delete the hidden 100MB boot or main Windows install.

If you click on the Ubuntu icon at the top of the Launcher on the left side, you can open dash and type in gparted.

http://castrojo.tumblr.com/post/4795149014/the-power-users-guide-to-unity

Comment: Excellent. I have found GParted from Dash!. This is what I wanted. Thanks a ton :).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a working, installed, Ubuntu you need to install it with

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

If you have an installation Live DVD and boot from it choose "install Ubuntu" and at some point you reach a "partitioning" section during the installation. That is gParted.

What you might want is the gParted Live: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php Works the same as the Ubuntu Live: burn the ISO, start system with DVD/CD and it will run gParted. It is a good tool for changing your disc without the need for a working operating system. So always handy.

Comment: Thanks. You have understood my question correctly :). I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

GParted preinstalled on Ubuntu liveCD.  If not, you can install gparted.
To do so, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: gparted is included in Ubuntu ISO, but is not in all the other flavors. You do have to install it in a working version of any Ubuntu or live version of the other flavors as you have posted.

Comment: I was reading the instruction at this site http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html. This has confused me, because during installation, it mentions that the GParted is available  at "System > Administration > Partition Editor'